# Text appear on hover image does not fit the image

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image

I've been working on a website and I'm trying to show some text when my mouse is hovering an image. This is a pretty common thing on website today I believe. However for some reasons when I hover my image the text goes "out of bonds" of the image. (I will attach a screenshot you'll understand)
[image: Image of my text going out of the bound of the image]
As you can see not only it goes below the image at the bottom, but also it goes through on the right of the image. I am not sure how to fix this? Is this because of the font size? I don't think so

```
div className='image_section'>
            <h1 className='section_title-top'>SERVICES </h1>
            <div className='img-container'>
                <div class="image">
                    <img class="image__img" src={bdh1Img} alt="Bricks" />
                    <div class="image__overlay image__overlay--primary">
                        <div class="image__title">This is my title and I want three same image</div>
                        <p class="image__description">
                            this is some random text
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                            adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, 
                            adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas 
                            ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, 
                            orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl 
                            sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.
                            Ut velit mauris, egestas sed, 
                            gravida nec, ornare ut, mi. Aenean 
                            ut orci vel massa suscipit pulvinar. Nulla sollicitudin. Fusce varius, ligula non tempus aliquam, 
                            nunc turpis ullamcorper nibh, in tempus sapien eros vitae ligula. Pellentesque
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
.image_section {
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 2rem 0;
}
.section_title-top{
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    padding: 2.5rem 0;
}

.img-container {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.image {
    position: relative;
}

.image p, h2{
    font-size: 14px;
}

.image__img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.image__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

.image__overlay > * {
    transform: translateY(20px);
    transition: transform 0.25s;
}

.image__overlay:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.image__overlay:hover > * {
    transform: translateY(0);
}


.image__title {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.image__description {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    margin-top: 0.35em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .img-container {
        max-width: 90%;
        margin: auto;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think this is too much text to be on an image
you can use ellipsis property like this

for example:

```css
.image__description {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    margin-top: 0.35em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3; /* this set the number of rows to show*/
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

then if want the user to display the full text u can make a modal to show the full text or something

Comment: Hi, thank you about this, this is true the text does affect the width of my black hover, however I want the text to show everything for the user when he hover I don't really want to add a modal (especially that I know it is doable)

Answer (score 0):

I saw that in the hover div (class name: image__overlay image__overlay--primary) you use position absulate so that it renders aspect of the main body. Add a width, it will be solved.

Comment: I tried to add a width, but if I put 100% it will be bigger than the image so I have to put less, I am not sure if it might create an issue later on though? And the height now does not go all the way down to the image if u see what I mean

Comment: Remove the max-width by width 100% in the class 'image__img' So that image will be the full width of the window. If you don't use any width the 'image__description' so that it will go left to right full width. The responsive issue will be solved.